# "Will there be a certain number of essays we are expected to send in per week?" is accurate?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

"Will there be a certain number of essays we are expected to send in per week?" Is this grammatically incorrect? Is there a mix in the tenses?

Comment: It's not ungrammatical, but it only makes sense if you're projecting into (1) the future / (2) the possible future [(1) When the new course starts, will ... // (2) If John and I enrol, will ...]. 'Are ...' is correct after 'It's good to have started the course, but I'm not totally sure about course requirements. Are ...?'].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth in the case of (1), would 'are' not interfere with the future tense? It seemed fine at first glance, however, after looking at it a few more times the 'are' started to stick out. Maybe I just need to re-learn grammar

Comment: 'We are expected to attend school tomorrow.' 'We are flying to Mallorca on Wednesday.' [wishful thinking] 'We are in on Friday'. 'We go to London on Thursday.' English often uses 'present constructions' (eg the continuous) / present tense to refer to future events.

Comment: I see now. Thank you!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, 'We are flying . . .' and similar sentences are **entirely** about the future, and are thus not analogous to the OP's sentence, which is about the expectation that exists **now**, but concerns something in the future.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes; I've not addressed the question completely. 'Will there be a certain number of essays that we will be expected to send in every week?' avoids the different-timeframe problem, but sounds clunky. 'Is there a certain number of essays we are expected to send in every week?' is fine, referring to a 'from time t=0 (not necessarily 'now')' situation and with a rule obtaining at the moment. Also, here,  'that we are expected to send in every week' can be a shortened form of 'that we are, when actually on the course, expected to send in every week'; it works with 'Will there be'.

Comment: The problem with the question is that the answer could be, “Yes”.   Instead why not ask, “How many essays are we expected to turn in each week?”  The answer could then be “5” or “There isn’t a set number- each week will be different.”  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question:

- Will there be a certain number of essays we are expected to send in per week?

is grammatically correct, being more or less equivalent to:

- Will there be a certain number of essays (expected) to be sent in per week?

An alternative and simpler question, with a slight change of focus, would be:

- Are we expected to send in a certain number of essays per week?

or

- Shall we be expected to send in a certain number of essays per week?

Comment: In the sentence "Will there be a certain number of essays (expected) to be sent in per week?", "to be" works in the same future tense as "Will there be". However in the original sentence, does "are" not affect the future tense in any way?

Comment: "to be sent in" is tenseless. "are expected" can refer to the present or future.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you so much!